# Variadic template data structures

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

Variadic templates are are templates that receive a varying number of arguments, and can use used with models that can operate with generic types

Code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    
    template <class ...Rest>
    struct Test {};
    
    template <class T, class ...Rest>
    struct Test <T, Rest...> {
        Test(T first, Rest... rest)
          : first(first)
         {}
    
        T first;
    };
    
    template <class T>
    void Print1(T &data)
    {
        std::cout << data.first << std::endl;
    }
    
    template <class T, class ...Rest>
    void Print2(Test<T, Rest...> &data)
    {
        std::cout << data.first << std::endl;
    }
    
    template <class T>
    struct Helper;
    
    template <class T, class ...Rest>
    struct Helper<Test<T, Rest...>> {
       static void Print(Test<T, Rest...> &data){
           std::cout << data.first << std::endl;
       }
    };
    
    int main() {
        Test<int, float, bool> ex(15, 41.59, true);
    
        using type = decltype(ex); //Test<int, float, bool>
      
        Print1(ex);
    
        Print2(ex);
    
        Helper<type>::Print(ex);
      
        std::cout << "END!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Observation: The reason for this question was asked to understand the varidiac template operation, for this reason I am not concerned with the use of the program, in this example above: The Test class is losing access to the generated sub-classes (rest ... )

***The question:***

1. **First topic of the doubt:** **I understand that functions and classes can have template , but what does <T, Rest ...> mean after the definition "class Test"?**, I already seen template < class T > class Some {}, but never template < class T > class Some < T > {}, See below my understanding of the case:

```
template <class T, class ...Rest>
void Func(T first, Rest ...rest){
    std::cout << first << std::endl;

    Func(rest...); //1 call is [T=float,Rest=<bool>], and 2 call is [T=bool] (Futures calls)
}
//Call: Func (1, 1.55, true), [T equals "int", Rest equals <float, bool>]
```

2. **Second topic of the doubt:** **In function "Print2", Why the template that was deduced for Print2 call is <int, float, bool>?** Since the first parameter is the variable "ex", I don't understand why the result is different from: [T = Test <int, float, bool>] (Print2<Test<int, float, bool>>). Instead, the result obtained was [T = int, Rest = <float, bool>] (Print2<int, float, bool>)
3. **Third topic of the doubt:** This topic mentions the 1st topic (where the <> is being defined after the structure) **The template is <class T, class ... Rest>. What does Test<T, Rest...> means after the definition "struct Helper"?** Note that it was used as follows: "**Test** <T, Rest ...>", instead of "<T, Rest ...>" in first (1st) topic
4. **Fourth topic of the doubt:** This topic mentions the 2st topic (where the template was deduced for Print2) **Why was it necessary to pass only Test <int, float, bool> as the type, instead of <int, float, bool>? What I want to know is how this self-deduction ("type" turns into -> [T=int, Rest=<float, bool>]) was made by C++?** Note that in the second topic, where the call to the function Print2, is equivalent to Print2 <int, flooat, bool>. using type = Test<int, float, bool>

Complements of the 4st topic: Helper::Print(ex), **"type" is equivalent** to Test<int, float, bool>, I noticed that "T" became, "int" (the first type), "Rest" became "<float, bool>" (the other types used to build the sutrct Test that is in variable "ex")

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [ask]. Only 1 question per question. Also, try to do some research on your own before asking. You are looking at [partial specializations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization).

Comment: @super Thanks, I didn't know which name to use to research, "partial specializations" along with the link helped a lot. I will do the research with this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dedicate this answer to @super that provides the link and the technical name for research. Thanks !

**1 and 3.** Let's suppose the template primary is:

```
template <size_t ...Rest>
struct Test {
   int value = 1;
};
```

This means that the others (partial specialization) can be deducted, and with this different methods and values within the Struct / Class can be defined, example:

```
template <size_t A>
struct Test <A, A*2> {
  int value = 2;
}
```

Any "Test" structure that was initialized with 2 parameters, and the second is the double of first (A*2) have value = 2. Example:

```
Test<5, 10> -> value = 2
Test <3, 6> -> value = 2;

Anything other than: "<A, A * 2>" will be assigned to the primary template

Test <1, 2, 3, 4> -> value = 1;
Test <4, 5> -> value = 1;
Test <3, 6, 8> -> value = 1;
```

**That said, replying to the first topic:**

```
template <class ...Rest>
struct Test {
  int value = 1;
};

template <class T, ...Rest>
struct Test <T, Rest...> {
  int value = 2;
};
```

The condition of the secondary template must satisfy the primary, which in this case is: "template <class ... Rest> struct Test {}", then any secondary template: template <class T, ... Rest> struct Test <T , Rest ...> will always be true, because Rest ... means 0 or more, and "T" is the first argument

Example below:

```
Test<int, bool> -> value = 2
Test <bool, float> -> value = 2
Test <bool> -> value = 2
Test <std::string> -> value = 2
```

But you can also create other secondary templates:

```
template <class ...Rest>
struct Test {
  int value = 1;
};

template <>
struct Test <int, float> {
  int value = 2;
};

template <class ...Rest>
struct Test <int, float, bool, Rest...> {
  int value = 3;
};
```

In this example above, you are saying:

If the type is "<int, float>" the value will be 2
[Exact two arguments, int and float]

If the type is <int, float, bool, Rest ...> the value will be 3
[The first three arguments are int and float and bool, the rest if any]

Example:

```
Test <int, float> -> value = 2

Test <int, float, bool> -> value = 3
Test <int, float, bool, std::string> -> value = 3
Test <int, floot, bool, std::string, char> -> value = 3

Any other that does not satisfy any of the secondary templates will be assigned to the primary

Test <bool, float> -> value = 1
Test <int> -> value = 1
Test <int, float, char> -> value = 1
```

**2.**
Let's assume the following code

```
...
template <class T, class ...Rest>
void Print(T data, Rest ...others){
   std::cout << data.first << std::endl;
}

int main(){
  Test<int, float, bool> ex(15, 41.59, true);

  Print(ex);
  return 0;
}
```

Print waits as a parameter (T data, Rest ... others), that is: "data" is of type T. Then T **data** will be "ex"

If we change the print func to Print(Test <T, Rest ...> & data), C ++ will understand that the template to be passed must be a structure or class that satisfies the condition to be true, example: Print < int, float, bool > (ex).

"< int, float, bool >" was obtained automatically by c / c ++ of the variable "ex"

See the example below:

```
...
template <class A, class B, class C>
void Print(Test<A, B, C> &data, A za, B zq){
    std::cout << data.first << std::endl;
    std::cout << za << std::endl; //float
    std::cout << zq << std::endl; //bool
}

int main(){
  Test<int, float, bool> ex(15, 41.59, true);

  Print(ex, 50);
  return 0;
}
```

Again "< int, float, bool >" was obtained automatically by c / c ++ of the variable "ex" when Print(ex)

A is "int"

B is "float'

C is "bool"

The second parameter (A za) of the function "Print", must the same type (int) of the parameter that was deducted by "A" (int), the same for the third parameter (B zq)

**3.** Let's assume the following code:

```
template <class T>
struct Helper {
  int value = 1;
};

template <>
struct Helper <int> {
  int value = 2;
};

template <class A, class B, class C>
struct Helper<Test<A, B, C>> {
   int value = 3;

   void PrintA(A value){}

   void PrintB(B value){}

   void PrintAll(A aval, B bval, C cval){}
};
```

Any "Helper" structure that was initialized with a single < int > parameter will have value = 2

Any "Helper" structure that was initialized with a single parameter different from < int > and Test<A, B, C> will have value = 1;

Example:

```
Helper<int> -> value = 2

Helper<Test<int,bool,float>> -> value = 3
Helper<Test<int,float,char>> -> value = 3
Helper<Test<char,std::string,double>> -> value = 3

Anything other than: "<int>" and "<Test<A,B,C>>" will be assigned to the primary template

Helper <bool> -> value = 1
Helper <float> -> value = 1
Helper <char> -> value = 1
```

Note that the secondary templates must satisfy the primary, ie: template < class T > struct Helper {}

Therefore, the secondary templates after the definition of "Helper" must contain only a single "T", example < int >, or < float >, or <Test <A, Rest ... >>

---

template <class A, class B, class C>
struct Helper <Test <A, B, C >>

This means: The template to be passed to Helper must be a type of struct / class that satisfies the expression, so:

Helper <Test <int, float, bool >> satisfies the condition, but

Helper <Test <int, float >> does not satisfy, because "A" was deducted for int, "B" for float, and "C" was empty